# Как передать кириллицу с EditText в Android Studio на сервер в соответствующей кодировке?

Tags: java, android, кодировка, utf-8

Считываю с `EditText`, отправляю строку на сервер, от сервера получаю знаки вопросов.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А какое отношение к этому вопросу имеет его заголовок?

Comment: У вас что-то где-то с кодировкой. Большего сказать по предоставленной вами информации нельзя.

Comment: Какая информация нужна? Кодировка проекта UTF-8. Латиницу считывает легко, а вот кириллицу... вместо букв - знаки вопроса.

Comment: Очевидно, то, что вам отправляет сервер совсем не в unicode. Поменяйте кодировку на UTF-8 и должно работать

Comment: Мое приложение шлет запросы на сайт, так вот если сайт открыть с браузера, то там уже будут знаки вопроса. И я абсолютно с Вами согласен что нужно где-то поменять кодировку на UTF-8. Узнать бы только где )). Есть способы перекодировать строку... я пробовал такие:         String str = new String (br.readLine().toString().getBytes(),"UTF-8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как JAVA string находится в кодировке UTF-16, а сервер UTF-8, то лично в моем случае помогла следующая кодировка

```
нужный стринг = new String(старый стринг.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Если строку отправляете на сервер через json, добавьте описание к передаваемому полю:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Спасибо, что не равнодушны к моей проблеме. Данные я отправляю через POST запрос.